# Hosting Strapi Application: Firebase vs. Digital Ocean - Seeking Cost-Effective Solutions and Best Practices

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, content-management-system, digital-ocean, strapi

I have a Strapi app that includes blogs and news with images. My goal is to host it, and I'm looking into Firebase and Digital Ocean. However, given the peculiarities of Firebase Hosting and Strapi's server-side nature, I'm not sure what the optimal strategy is.

#### Firebase Options: Functions vs. Cloud Run

- **Firebase Hosting Limitations:**
  Firebase Hosting looks to be designed for static material, whereas Strapi, as a server-side application, presents a hurdle.
- **Firebase Functions Query:**
  Can Firebase Functions efficiently host a Strapi application? If so, what is the suggested configuration for handling server-side logic?
- **Firebase Cloud Run Suitability:**
  Firebase Cloud Run Suitability: Is it a better option for hosting a Strapi application?

#### Exploring Digital Ocean

- **Alternative Consideration:**
  I'm also curious if Digital Ocean could provide a better hosting environment for Strapi.

#### Cost-Effective Hosting Priority

- **Primary Concern:**
  My primary issue is finding a cost-effective hosting option.

#### Seeking Guidance and Best Practices

I'm looking for guidance from the community. If you have experience hosting Strapi on Firebase or Digital Ocean, your knowledge is invaluable. In addition, any best practices or cost-effectiveness considerations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

firebase is good and versatile for serverless approach ,with mainly focus on frontend requirements ,you can still develop very eficent backend with the [firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) and of course with other google cloud products that gives you all the industry stander approach with fixable and top of that you can set rules for your database to make more secure.

but with digital ocean you will have more flexibility and control over your hosting environment. With Digital Ocean, you can set up a VPS (virtual private server) and also it gives you full control over the server configuration like  install and configure the necessary dependencies and run the server-side code as your requirement.

my suggestion is your application is focused to implement heavy work on server (which in this case i am assuming is true) then go with digital ocean.

so firebase hosting can be used for hosting the frontend assets of your Strapi app as firebase provide all the useful functionality like real-time database, authentication, cloud messaging more ,and  use digital ocean provides more flexibility and control for hosting the server-side part.

Comment: Currently the entire frontend of the website to which the strapi application is connected is hosted on firebase and the free tier of firebase is more than enough for running the website. I am pretty sure you need to move to a paid plan to integrate server-side.

But I heard that digitalocean is cheaper compared to firebase

Comment: yse it could be cheaper but what i said is that ,if you finds the functionality like real-time database, authentication, cloud messaging and lot more to be quit useful and handy then use it for that purpose other wise if the digital ocean serve you all of your need then just stick with that  .